# Design patterns for live coding/script reloading

Tags: c++, scripting, design-patterns, lua

I would like to make C++/Lua combo and write scripts for a game with live script reloading. What design patterns should I be aware of so not to cause me unnecessary pain?

For example if I have a simple MUD game with enemies and maps, I can bind a Lua function which would remove all the enemies and recreate them based on the data(which I would modify with Lua script).

That sounds easy, but haven't done so I think there may be some deadends without proper planning.

What are the best design patterns and solutions for live script reloading?

Comment: avoid Singleton ;)